# I'm trying to update state in an object nested within an array... with json data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

So the goal is to fetch data from the google books API, which returns JSON data in the same form as my state shows. I want to update *title* with the title string returned by the JSON data. Right now I get a "failed to compile" on the line I've marked in the code. Then, I would like to pass the title as a props to the List component, which would render it as a list item with each map through. So if 20 books' data are fetched, I would render 20 different titles. I'm new to react so I'm not sure how much is wrong here.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import List from './List.js';

export default class Main extends Component {
    state ={
        items : [{
            volumeInfo : {
                title : "",
            }
        }]
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers+inauthor:keyes&key=AIzaSyAWQ0wFzFPQ3YHD_uLDC7sSs-HPRM3d__E`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    items : [{
                        volumeInfo : {
                            title : result.items.map((book) => {
                                const name = book.volumeInfo.title;
                                return name;
                            })
                        } 
                    }] });
            })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <header>
                    <h2>Google Book Search</h2>
                </header>
                <List title={this.state.items}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here's List.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class List extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>{this.props.items}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, your code is missing the closing parenthese of the `map()` function (in the line right above the //error comment), that's probably the reason for the compilation error.

Comment: Also, you're mapping the result of the fetch into the `title` property instead of `items` property, so `items` stays the same and now the `title` becomes an array of object, which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: Finally, you're passing `this.state.title` to the `List` component, but there is no such thing as a property called `title` in the state object, you need to pass `this.state.items` instead, and please include the code for _./List.js_ in the question.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi ok, I see. I've updated the code to reflect List, and .items instead of .title. I'm not sure how to map the result to the title property.

Comment: I added an answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the result of your `fetch()` has the same structure as your `items` property of the state, all you need to do in the `then()` callback is to set the result in the state directly as shown below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('your/long/url')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ items: (result.items || []) });
    });
}
```

Now that your state is updated with the needed data, you need to pass it as a prop to your ***List*** component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <header>
                <h2>Google Book Search</h2>
            </header>
            <List items={ this.state.items } />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Finally, in your ***List*** component, you can make use of this prop by rendering it in a `map()` call:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                { this.props.items.map((book, i) => (
                    <li key={ i }>{ book.volumeInfo.title }</li>
                )) }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what's happening here:
```({ items: (result || []) });```

Comment: Absolutely, the outer `({` is assinging the result of the `fetch()` into the `items` property of the state. The `x || []` is a protective layer that prevents assigning a null value in that state property. This is useful later in the _List_ component so that the `items.map()` call doesn't throw "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". (in case the `fetch()` did not return anything)

Comment: I see. So this makes a lot of sense to me, and it's cleaner/more compartmentalized. However, I'm getting an "this.props.items.map is not a function" error

Comment: Oh, my bad, it should be `result.items`. Correcting my answer now.

Comment: No problem, I should've been able to catch that myself. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class Main extends Component {

  state ={
    items : []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers+inauthor:keyes&key=AIzaSyAWQ0wFzFPQ3YHD_uLDC7sSs-HPRM3d__E`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
      const titleList = result.items.map((item)=>{return item.volumeInfo.title});
      this.setState({items: titleList})
        })    
  };

  render(){
    const {items} = this.state;
    const titleComponent = items.length > 0
        ? items.map((item)=>{
            return <List title={item} />
          }) 
        : null;
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <header>
          <h2>Google Book Search</h2>
       </header>
       {titleComponent}
    </div>
  )
  }
}
```

Above code should be worked if your List component is working fine.

Comment: You're right, that did it. I'm going to study what you did here.

Comment: We can discuss via chat

Answer (score 0):

Change the setState function with this

```
this.setState({
                    items : [{
                        volumeInfo : {
                            title : result.items.map((book) => {
                                const name = book.volumeInfo.title;
                                return name;
                            })
                        } 
                    }] });
```

Looks like brackets was the issue.

Comment: Yes you're right, that fixed the error. Now it seems that I'm not correctly updating state with the data. Any idea why?

Comment: You are passing this.state.title instead of this.state.volumeInfo and you have to use title from props in your List component.